# Why is there a 'Minor Model Age Disclosure' in GIMP under 'Edit Metadata'?

Tags: gimp, metadata

Recently I went to Image -> Metadata -> Edit Metadata -> IPTC Extension in GIMP, and when I scrolled down I found 'Model Age', but with a 'Minor Model Age Disclosure' option underneath it.
It's a drop down list with options from 'Age Unknown' to 'Age 14 Or Under' to 'Age 25 And over'.
Why would I need to enter ages like that when I can just enter it in the textbox above?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's included because it's part of the [IPTC Photo Metadata Standard 2019.1](https://www.iptc.org/std/photometadata/specification/IPTC-PhotoMetadata#minor-model-age-disclosure).